# Difficulties with a repeat that should print a list of images in the VFP

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have some images in Documents, and I am saving the link to these images in a list, the idea is that all the images contained in that list are printed in a `contentType="application/msword"` but for some reason the images do not appear, but when I put the direct link by a `<img src="link"/>`
the image appears right..

Controller:

```apex
public Integer cont=0;
Set<String> strDocNameSet = new Set<String>();
List<Document> strDocUrlList = new List<Document>();
List<String> links = new List<String>();

public void fillQuoteLineItemInfo() {
    lstQuoteLineItems = [Select Id,Position__c,SubTotal,Total_Per_Position__c, Grand_Total__c, Position_price_with_taxes__c, PIS_COF__c, ICMS__c, IPI__c, Description, Quantity,PriceBookEntry.Product2.Name,NET_Price_R__c,NCM_number__c,
                         UnitPrice, ICMS_ST__c, Manufact_Plant_QLI__c from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId = :quoteObj.Id Order BY Position__c];
   
    for(QuoteLineItem i:lstQuoteLineItems){
        strDocNameSet.add(i.Manufact_Plant_QLI__c);
    }
}

public List<String>getImgProd(){
    strDocUrlList=[Select Id,Name,LastModifiedById from Document where Name IN : strDocNameSet];
    for(Document i:strDocUrlList){
        string strOrgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        string url = 'https://'+ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')+ '/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id='+strDocUrlList[cont].Id+'&oid=' + strOrgId;
        System.debug('url cru:  ' + url);
        url = url.replace('visualforce', 'documentforce');
        System.debug('url replace:  ' + url);
        links.add(url);
        cont++;
    }
    return links;
}
```

VFP:

```html
<img src="https://guentner--partial--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0158B0000009A8ZQAU&oid=00D8B0000004co8UAA"/>
<apex:repeat value="{!ImgProd}" var="item">
    <a href="https://www.guntner.com.br/">
        <apex:image url="{!ImgProd}" styleClass="photo" width="200" height="30"/><br/><br/>
    </a>
</apex:repeat>
```

My idea was to use repeat and show all the images in the doc...
I opened the Word document with NotePad++ to compare the links...see

```html
<img src="https://guent--partial--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0158B0000009A8ZQAU&amp;oid=00D8B0000004co8UAA" />

<a href="#">
    <img src="[https://guent--partial--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0158B0000009A8ZQAU&oid=00D8B0000004co8UAA%5D" height="30" width="200" class="photo" /><br /><br />
</a>
```

The `oid` is different and I fear a "[" before http.

does anyone know how to solve this? I'm open to a workaround as well....I just need to print this list with links that redirect to images. Thanks for listening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents are not images. Documents can contain images, but generally can't contain other documents. You'll need to use an indirect solution, such as using Fancybox or something. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958186/2132791) for more details.